# python structs, unwanted extra bytes

Tags: python, struct

I am writing a bitmap file using python. My code to create the bitmap header is:

```
pack('bblll', 66, 77, fileLength, 0, 122)
```

Unless my math is wrong, (Which, it's not) this should create a string of bytes that is 14 bytes long.

b = char (1 byte)
l = long (4 bytes)

1 + 1 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 14

But, the thing is, I receive 2 extra bytes; Say I have a filelength of 142, I would receive the following (in hexidecimal):

```
42 4D 00 00 8E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 7A 00 00 00
```

The 2 extra bits are nulls at offset 0x2 and 0x3. Where do They come from? And How do I get rid of them? It is corrupting my images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It pads to four-byte (word) boundaries so the `long`s start at natural offsets (i.e. offsets that are a multiple of four), use the `=` prefix (or any other of the possible byte order prefixes) to prevent this.

[More info on this documentation page.](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct-alignment)

Comment: You are my hero. I must have looked right over that; A little while ago, I had to use little endian by using a '<', can't believe I missed that.